# Is it possible to set miner reward on Geth clique?

Tags: mining, testnets, poa, clique

I have a private network set up with ethereum & PoA clique consensus.
Using in geth client

```
 miner.setEtherbase(eth.coinbase)
```

on miner nodes, doesn't seems to work. 
Inspecting in block explorer miner is always "0x00..."
But at the same time, the "0x00.." account has balance 0.
Where are all fees?

Answer (score 1):

There is no mining reward in clique consensus algorithm. The sealer information is already included in extradata field.